# select the first n largest groups from grouped data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Data frame(df) structure

```
col1    col2
x   3131
y   9647
y   9648
z   9217
y   9652
x   23
```

grouping:

```
grouped = df.groupby(col1)
```

I want to select first 2 largest groups i.e.,

```
y 9647
y 9648
y 9652
```

and

```
x 3131
x 23
```

How can I do that using pandas. I've achieved it using list but that makes it clumsy again as it becomes a list of tuples and I've to convert them back to data frame types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with indexing index and filter rows by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['col1'].isin(df['col1'].value_counts().index[:2])]
print (df1)
  col1  col2
0    x  3131
1    y  9647
2    y  9648
4    y  9652
5    x    23
```

If need DataFrames by top groups use dictionary comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
dfs = {i: df[df['col1'].eq(x)] for i, x in enumerate(df['col1'].value_counts().index[:2], 1)}
print (dfs)
{1:   col1  col2
1    y  9647
2    y  9648
4    y  9652, 2:   col1  col2
0    x  3131
5    x    23}
```

---

```
print (dfs[1])
  col1  col2
1    y  9647
2    y  9648
4    y  9652

print (dfs[2])
  col1  col2
0    x  3131
5    x    23
```